# Not reading number properly?

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read from file line by line. It takes the first number of the line and the rest it connects it using a char of linked list. But when I run it, i get the connection as `-38` (which is wrong) and it only prints it once and does not go through the rest of the line. but it reads first element perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};


int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    char * storage;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    struct node *G[1000];
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        G[i]= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        G[i]->data = i;
        G[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    fp = fopen("idk2.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        int vertexGettingConntected = line[0];
        struct node* newItem;
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :", read);
        int i = 0;
        while(line[i] != '\0'){
          if ( line[i] == ' '){
            i++;
          }
          else if (i == 0){
            newItem = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            int itemStorage = line[0] - '0';
            newItem->next = NULL;
            newItem->data = itemStorage;
            G[itemStorage] = newItem;
            printf("This is first Number:%d\n", itemStorage);
          }
          else if (line[i] != ' '){
            struct node* addingItem = newItem;
            while(addingItem->next != NULL){
              addingItem = addingItem->next;
            }
            int itemStorage = line[i] - '0';
            struct node* newConnection = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            addingItem->next = newConnection;
            newConnection->data = itemStorage;
            newConnection->next = NULL;
            printf("This is character:%c\n", line[i]);
            printf("This is connection:%i\n", itemStorage);
          }
          i++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    for(int printer = 1; printer<20; printer++){
        printf("%d\n",G[printer]->data);
    }
  }
```

EDIT: 
Just wanted to include file im reading from:

```
1 3 4
2 4
3 1 4
4 2 1 3
```

Comment: First of all, `line` is never allocated any space that I can see, so you have undefined behavior. Literally anything can happen. Where is `getline()` defined?

Comment: @torstenvl `getline()` allocates mem.

Comment: @NeverSleepAlwaysCode Why is your code one sole spaghetti in main? Don't you know how to write functions yet?

Comment: @Swordfish I am required by my professor to write the read in file in the main. I had divided my code before into functions and lost 20 points for not following guidelines which makes it confusing for me.

Comment: Ideally, i would prefer to have a separate function to read file and another to allocate into array.

Comment: Makes it easier to debug as well

Comment: Note: `if (line)
        free(line);` may be simplified to `free(line);`.  The `if (line)` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to have an array of pointers to `node` which you all allocate memory for at the beginning of your program without knowing how many `node`s will be needed. Then you allocate memory again while reading from the file.

Given the constraints of not being allowed to use functions, thats how i'd read the file and build a list:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_tag {
    int value;
    struct node_tag *next;
} node_t;

int main(void)
{
    char const *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *input_file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!input_file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading :(\n\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // read from file and build a list:
    node_t *head = NULL;
    node_t *tail = NULL;
    int value;
    int result = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    while (fscanf(input_file, "%d", &value) == 1) {
        node_t *new_node = calloc(1, sizeof *new_node);
        if (!new_node) {
            fputs("Not enough memory :(\n\n", stderr);
            result = EXIT_FAILURE;
            goto glean_up;
        }

        new_node->value = value;

        if (!head) {  // there is no head yet so new_node becomes the head
            head = tail = new_node;  // which is also the lists tail
            continue;
        }

        tail->next = new_node;
        tail = new_node;
    }

    // print the list:
    for (node_t *current_node = head; current_node; current_node = current_node->next)
        printf("%d ", current_node->value);
    putchar('\n');


clean_up:
    fclose(input_file);

    for (node_t *current_node = head, *temp; current_node; current_node = temp) {
        temp = current_node->next;
        free(current_node);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Ideally you'd write functions to manage the list:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_tag {
    int value;
    struct node_tag *next;
} node_t;

typedef struct list_tag {
    node_t *head;
    node_t *tail;
} list_t;

void list_create(list_t *list)
{
    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
}

bool list_push_back(list_t *list, int value)
{
    node_t *new_node = calloc(1, sizeof *new_node);
    if (!new_node)
        return false;

    new_node->value = value;

    if (!list->head) {
        list->head = list->tail = new_node;
        return true;
    }

    list->tail->next = new_node;
    list->tail = new_node;
    return true;
}

void list_print(list_t *list)
{
    for (node_t *current_node = list->head; current_node; current_node = current_node->next)
        printf("%d ", current_node->value);
}

void list_free(list_t *list)
{
    for (node_t *current_node = list->head, *temp; current_node; current_node = temp) {
        temp = current_node->next;
        free(current_node);
    }
}

bool read_int(FILE *input_file, int *value)
{
    return fscanf(input_file, "%d", value) == 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char const *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *input_file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!input_file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading :(\n\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // read from file and build a list:
    list_t list;
    list_create(&list);
    int value;

    while (read_int(input_file, &value)) {
        if (!list_push_back(&list, value)) {
            fputs("Not enough memory :(\n\n", stderr);
            // clean up:
            fclose(input_file);
            list_free(&list);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    // print the list:
    list_print(&list);
    putchar('\n');

    // clean up:
    fclose(input_file);
    list_free(&list);
}
```

#### Output:

```
1 3 4 2 4 3 1 4 4 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hit a space character you iterate i. At the end of your loop you iterate i.

So when you hit a space character you iterate i twice, skipping the number and landing on the next space character.

Which is why you get the first number but miss the rest.

edit: removed getline() comments due to feedback from @swordfish. Current implementation is not problematic.